# swagger-jsdocs: YAMLException: bad indentation of a mapping entry

Tags: swagger-jsdocs

Need help swagger-jsdoc documentation. This is the first time I am working with. I get the following error for the below @swagger jsdoc documentation.

```
/**
 * @swagger
 *  /v1/expected_rate/get_objects:
 *  get: 
 *      description: Get objects for the user logged in company.
 *  tags: 
 *  - ObjectGenerator
 *  produces: application/json
 *  responses:
 *  '200':
 *      description:A successful response. Returns a Array of Objects.
 *      examples:
 *          application/json: 
 *          - {
 *              "prop_1": 1,
 *              "prop_2": "123456789",
 *              "prop_3": 438,
 *              "prop_4": 1 
 *          }
 */
```

Error: YAMLException: bad indentation of a mapping entry at line 10, column 14:
examples:
^
at module.exports (C:\Documents\node_modules\swagger-jsdoc\lib\index.js:37:11)
at Object. (C:\GIT Repository\app.js:91:19)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:651:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:498:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:695:10)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:201:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:516:3)

Answer (score 0):

The indentation does not look right. Try the following:

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * /v1/expected_rate/get_objects:
 *   get: 
 *     description: Get objects for the user logged in company.
 *     tags: 
 *       - ObjectGenerator
 *     produces:
 *       - application/json
 *     responses:
 *       '200':
 *         description: A successful response. Returns a Array of Objects.
 *         examples:
 *           application/json: 
 *             - {
 *                 "prop_1": 1,
 *                 "prop_2": "123456789",
 *                 "prop_3": 438,
 *                 "prop_4": 1 
 *               }
 */
```

Comment: Helen - Thank you, Indentation was an issue. I resolved this. Thank you for responding.